# Как получить SelectedItems из динамически созданных ListBox

Tags: vb.net

В цикле создается несколько ListBox, а вот как получить из них выделенные элементы?

```
Dim listbox1000 As New ListBox
listbox1000.Name = "rb" & i
listbox1000.Location = New Point(12, 104)
listbox1000.Width = 607
listbox1000.Height = 276
listbox1000.SelectionMode = SelectionMode.MultiSimple
listbox1000.Visible = False
Me.Controls.Add(listbox1000)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Берите листбоксы прямо из `Me.Controls`

```
Dim listBox As ListBox = Me.Controls.Find("rb1", False)(0)
```

На месте `rb1` указывайте имя (`Name`) нужного листбокса.

Comment: Спасибо огромное)